# How to add 'selected' attribute for nested_form select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using this [NestedForm](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) gem for dynamically adding form fields,
but when adding a selectbox field it doesn't have the "selected" attribute,

```
<%= nested_form_for [@website, @website_rule] do |f| %>
 <%= f.fields_for :website_dynamic_rules do |rule_form| %>
                <%= rule_form.select :all_pages, [['Yes', true], ['No', false]],{}, { :class => 'all-pages'%>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not seeing the `selected` attribute in one of the `option` elements, my guess would be that you have a value of `nil` in the `all_pages` attribute rather than a value of `false`.  To see if this is the case you can temporarily add something like this in your view:

```
<%= f.fields_for :website_dynamic_rules do |rule_form| %>
  <%= rule_form.object.inspect %>
```

That will show you the object that is being used and you can review the value for `all_pages`.  If it is `nil`, one possible solution would be to define a default value in the migration.  When you first add the column, you would want to use something like:

```
add_column :website_rules, :all_pages, :boolean, default: false
```